# What are some rules of thumb for naming classes that extend Android's Activity class?

Tags: android, naming-conventions, android-activity, naming

I go back and forth about how to name activity classes.  Activity seems to imply a verb, like EditContact, for example.  But that seems more like what one would call the Intent that triggers EditContact.  Should the activity be named ContactEditor instead?

Comment: Since there isn't a 'correct' answer I'd tag this as Community Wiki if I were you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked with a few projects and there doesn't seem to be a set way of doing it, and generally I follow the golden rule of name something by what it does. In this case, ContactEditor would be better, save your verbs for functions.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question. There is no right answer to this.

Personal opinion: Activities represent "places" in my application, so I name them accordingly: UserSettingsEditorActivity, MainScreenActivity, etc..

Comment: I like this, but disagree with appending Activity to everything, for the same reasons [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) is (generally) frowned upon.